# Change the width of bootstrap container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to change the .container div width in bootstrap 4.
The original css is this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    max-width: 1160px;
}
```

If i add this code below to my file, would it cause any problems, or everything will be okay?

```
    @media (min-width: 1920px)
.container {
    max-width: 1360px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change most of the default settings/values in bootstrap but remember that if you change them you might lose the responsive layout which Bootstrap provides it to you, but the answer is Yes you can and it is all about your own project.

If you don't sure you can change only a container called it with ID and then do changes to that one only.

Always refer back to documentation that Bootstrap provided.

[enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)